# Strange issue with 2D arrays in c

Tags: mysql, c, multidimensional-array

I am working on a C project at the moment and I am having an issue with using 2D arrays. Before I begin, I am very new to C so forgive me if this is a straight forward question.

What I am trying to do, is initialise an array, and pass this to a function to retrieve the results. Once complete, the original function can loop through the array.

The array contains 50 rows of 2 elements.

Below is how I am initialising the array and calling the function.

```
char* array[][2] = {0};
    int result = loadArray(&HandleDB, &array);
```

below is the function for the loadArray

```
int loadArray(MYSQL *HandleDB, char *array[][2])
{
    int sqlLen = 0;
    char *sql;
    MYSQL_RES *resultReport;
    MYSQL_ROW rowReport;

    sqlLen = asprintf(&sql, "SELECT * FROM TblLookups");

    SL_DebugAll(DBG_ALWAYS, sql);
    if ((mysql_real_query(HandleDB, sql, sqlLen)))
    {
        printf("MySQL Error: %s\n", mysql_error(HandleDB));
        return 1;
    }

    resultReport = mysql_use_result(HandleDB);

    int i = 0;
    while ((rowReport = mysql_fetch_row(resultReport)))
    {

        array[i][0] = rowReport[0];
        array[i][1] = rowReport[1];
        printf("%s:%s\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("***\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        printf("%s:%s\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem I am having is printing out the contents of the array after the while loop is wrong but within the while loop is correct.

For example, within the while loop where it is getting the value from a MySQL result and then printing what it stored in the array I get the following output:

```
colA1:colB1
colA2:colB2
colA3:colB3
```

When I then loop through in the for loop the same array I get the following

```
:colB1
:colA1
:colB2
:colA3
:colB3
:colA2
```

I don't understand why this isn't working in the for loop but is in the while loop when the printf statement is the same code accessing the same array.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `char* array[][2] = {0};` doesn't compile for me with gcc and generates a 1x2 array with MSVC.  You say the array has 50 rows - where do you extend `array` to provide storage for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for iterating over the multi-dimensional array is fine.  However, you're storing character pointers `(char *)` in the array.  This means you're not actually storing the result strings themselves, but their location in memory at the time that you stored them.  However, that location is changed internally by MySQL every time you call `mysql_fetch_row(resultReport)`, so your character pointers end up pointing to different or invalid data.

The proper way to store the results is to create a copy of the strings and make your array elements point to the copy.  One way to do this is

```
while ((rowReport = mysql_fetch_row(resultReport)))
{

    array[i][0] = strdup(rowReport[0]);
    array[i][1] = strdup(rowReport[1]);
    printf("%s:%s\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. But I have a minor confusion. The result set is constant throughout the function and `mysql_fetch_row` will retrieve the row from the result set, then why will the location of the row change if `mysql_fetch_row` only retrieves it from the result set? (If I am wrong please correct me)

Comment: MySQL could be recycling the result set after it's retrieved, since once you call `mysql_fetch_row` I don't believe there's another way to get that row from MySQL again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that fixed it, I forgot about how char* work and pointers.